# can't using same data as option in different modal box

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I have two modal in one page. One is for edit and the other is for create. In both modal contain select2 option. And the option I get from my database. I want to use the data for both of modal. But I get error in modal create and no error for modal edit. In modal create, it can't display the data in select option. Can anyone help me?

I try this

```
  public function detail_produk(){
    $data['item']=$this->admin_model->get_all_detail_produk();
    $data['ukuran'] = $this->admin_model->get_ukuran();
    $data['sidebar'] = $this->load->view('sidebar','',TRUE);
    $data['header'] = $this->load->view('header','',TRUE);
    $this->load->view('detail_produk', $data);
}
```

The View

```
   <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="detail_user">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Ukuran</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" id="ukuran">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Pilih Ukuran</option>
            <?php foreach ($ukuran as $ukuran) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $ukuran['id'];?>"><?php echo $ukuran['size'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" id="button-simpan" class="btn btn-primary mr-auto" >Simpan</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Kembali</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="tambah">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <form id="form1">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Ukuran</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" id="ukuran_id">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Pilih Ukuran</option>
            <?php foreach ($ukuran as $ukuran) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $ukuran['id'];?>"><?php echo $ukuran['size'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" id="button-tambah" class="btn btn-primary mr-auto" >Tambah</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Kembali</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($ukuran as $ukuran)
```

You can not use same variable. Do something like follows

```
foreach ($ukuran as $value){
    //now you can
    echo $value['id'];
}
```